Что менее затратно: box collider 2d trigger или постоянное создание Physics2D.BoxCast?
При разовом или редком использование понятно, но при частом или постоянном использование, моё предположение, разницы нету. Так ли это?

Нет, это не так. События вычисляются при симуляции физики, которая планово просчитывается в своём потоке, а касты это дополнительные вычисления в основном потоке.
